# specs2: How to use "failtrace" option

Tags: scala, stack-trace, specs2

In my specs2 tests, I frequently use helper functions to test groups of conditions at once. Unfortunately, that makes the line number output of failed tests useless, since all failures are on the same line.

Google turned up that there's a "failtrace" option that will output the stack trace of failure. However, I can't find an example of how to actually use that. Is it in `build.sbt`? Is it used on the SBT command line? Is it set somehow in the constructor of the `Specification` class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `failtrace` option at the specification level:

```
class MySpec extends org.specs2.mutable.Specification {
  args.report(failtrace = true)
  ...
}
```

You can also pass `failtrace` on the sbt command line:

```
sbt> test-only *MySpec* -- failtrace
```

Answer (score 0):

Eric's solution can also be applied to all tests run by SBT by including the following in your build.sbt file:

```
testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.Specs2, "failtrace")
```

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517699/how-to-change-play-framework-2-test-settings-to-show-complete-stacktraces) for an explanation on how to do this for other testing frameworks.