# Spec2 :how to see failing test stacktrace and resolve "parseBody" keyword not found

Tags: scala, scalatra, scalatra-sbt, spec2

I need to know two things here :
1. How to see the stacktrace of the failing test case? Right now I only see the line number it failed and the result. See the outcome of the test case below :

```
 
x return status 200
[error]    '404' is not equal to '200' (LayoutControllerSpec.scala:20)
```

2. My controller uses parseBody keyword to parse json provided by JacksonJsonSupport class. how to write the test case for the action me below :

```
val create = post() {
      var layout:Layout = parsedBody.extract[Layout] //Layout is model class
      ....
}
```

Any help or ideas would be highly appreciated.
Thanks,
PS: This code is written for scalatra framework using spec2 framework.

Comment: I think you should ask these two questions separately as they are two different questions.

Comment: Can you please validate the answer if it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Let's answer the first question here.

You can use the `failtrace` argument to get a stacktrace for a failure

```
sbt> test-only *MySpec* -- failtrace
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114020/specs2-how-to-use-failtrace-option).